# How to edit a documents outline in pdf-tools?

Tags: pdf, pdf-tools

By pressing `o` you can open the outline for the pdf document. Is there any way you can also add new sections with the corresponding pages to this outline?

Comment: I don't think you can edit a pdf with `pdf-tools`, beyond adding annotations.